# Русскоязычный SO — не англоязычный SO

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, хэшкод

Коллеги! Уже больше месяца, как старый добрый Хэшкод переехал на площадку StackExchange, и, разумеется, многое стало гораздо лучше — от более продвинутого, удобного движка до популярного имени сайта, которое приносит к нам гораздо больше посетителей, чем прежде.

Тем не менее, это не означает, что мы внезапно *превратились* в StackOverflow. У нас, честно говоря, покамест гораздо меньше активных участников. У нас не так много специалистов по разным, даже довольно популярным, темам в программировании. И — что тоже очень важно! — у нас тут *другое* сообщество, с другими, устоявшимися традициями и другим видением себя.

Тем не менее, я замечаю, что некоторые вещи у нас происходят таким образом, какой был бы, возможно, уместен на английском SO, но не вполне подходит для нас. Например, «борьба» за идеальность меток хорошо для сайта, в котором это представляет серьёзную проблему. У нас же эта проблема ни в коей мере не является главной. Так же как и проблема незакрытых вопросов четырёхлетней давности (будут хорошие ответы — гугл переиндексирует их быстро!).

На мой взгляд, главная наша проблема сейчас — объективный недостаток свежих ответов по сравнению с возросшим количеством вопросом. Который, разумеется, возникает из-за недостаточного количества активных знатоков на сайте.

Поэтому гораздо более уместно, как мне кажется, направить усилия на привлечение хороших специалистов на сайт. Какие могут быть пути для этого? Простейший путь — установление доброжелательной атмосферы, мотивирующей новичков давать ответы и улучшать их. Причём **не** путём критики, минусования и удаления — это только отпугнёт адекватных людей. Давайте дадим людям почувствовать, что они здесь нужны! Текущая атмосфера не мотивирует даже старожилов сайта принимать участие в его работе, я заметил, что некоторые верные в прошлом участники теперь появляются на сайте существенно реже.

Затем, возможно, стоит как-то использовать наши пока небольшие размеры и *обозримость*. То, что мы не такие большие, как английский SO, даёт возможность привнести нотку социальности в общение.

Далее, если мы откажемся от слепого копирования формата английского SO, возможно, мы сумеем осветить тематику, интересную другим специалистам. Здесь, конечно, есть риск уйти от основной тематики сайта, и, конечно, потребует филигранной работы модераторов. Тем не менее, неформатные или близкие к тому вопросы существуют и на английском SO, и приносят свою часть славы: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406760/276994), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/276994), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234075/276994), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/276994), [[5]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/154101), [[6]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21053/154101), [[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218123/276994) (хотя, как замечают на Reddit'е, "Best of Stack Overflow, almost guaranteed to be locked as not constructive!").

Есть ли у вас ещё какие-то идеи по улучшению нашего сайта?

Comment: На русском SO не ты отвечаешь на вопрос, а вопрос отвечает на тебя.

Comment: @igumnov: ... ругает твой код и материт твоего преподавателя? :-)

Comment: SO - система "вопрос-ответ". Пусть, хоть вопросы будут качественные, даже если их все переписать надо. Я не лезу в мейнстрим, но на подписанных метках читать нечего. Именно потому, что качество самого вопроса нулевое. Хотя новички - самые полезные участники, потому что они генерируют контент. Почему бы не сделать ставку на правку?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov: Правка — это хорошо. Правка и спасение старых вопросов — почётный, хотя и неблагодарный труд (ведь вопрос скорее всего брошен, и ответ принят не будет). Но улучшение свежих вопросов куда более полезно для сайта.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov: Но конечно хотелось бы не отпугнуть людей _слишком_ активными правками. Человек, пришедший на сайт, не должен чувствовать себя _контентом_. Всё же и в вопросах, и в ответах хороших участников есть индивидуальность. И это хорошо.

Comment: @VladD, делаю все, что в моих силах. Мы с сообществ по Диску Google и по Google Apps отправляем на готовые решения сюда. Правда, публикаций пока не много и это капля в море, но совместный разум лучше индивидуальных потуг.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov: Круто! Спасибо вам!

Comment: Is it acceptable if I will post answers here but in English? Is here any policy that dos not allow me to do that? Because I have some negative comments here http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423931/180915. Any comments are welcome. I am 100% Russian speaking, but I have no cyrillic keyboard and it is easier for me just write in English.

Comment: @Alex: Ну, хм. Сообщения на английском — неформат, это почти всё равно как на en.SO писать на русском. Может, вам подойдёт http://translit.ru? Sorry for that.

Comment: On english SO I regularly meet messages in French or Spanish not so many. And my question is not about ask everybody here to switch into English, but just about policy and general goal of the site. Would you prefer to have some answers in English here or not to have at all?

Comment: @Alex: Мне кажется (не могу говорить за всех), что это было бы не вполне вежливо по отношению к тем участникам, которые не очень хорошо говорят на английском. Те, кто знает английский, и так в привилегированном положении в силу того, что могут задать тот же вопрос на (пускай корявом) английском на en.SO.

Comment: I have absolutely opposite opinion. But since you are the second person who is telling that English is not welcome here, I would respect you and other people here then and not post my answers in English. But I see no reason or added value why people prefer to keep question unanswered than to put some effort to read English, especially for IT people who has to learn English anyway.

Comment: @Alex: У нас как раз есть [дискуссия на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/342/10105) по этому поводу. Если вы выскажетесь там, возможно, вам ответят и другие. Моё мнение — лишь мнение одного человека. Какой бы консенсус не был принят всеми, всем придётся ему подчиниться.

Comment: I would prefer not comment there. The user posted is the same which commented my answer. The way he speaks is not very polite. So I would prefer keep my knowledge and experience for other people who can say simple "thanks" but not "только вот их забыли спросить" ;-)

Comment: Имхо любой кодер должен хоть как то понимать английский, потому-что он на нем выражает свои мысли. (1Сникам привет. Кстати,а почему нет 1С на мордовском?)

Comment: @Alex: Очень жаль. Нам нужны специалисты, но мы не можем уйти от формата. Если у вас вдруг появится возможность и желание писать на русском, возвращайтесь. (По поводу технических средств, я в аналогичной ситуации пользуюсь [вот этим плагином](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/transliterator/).)

Comment: @Alex, при отсутствии русскоязычной клавиатуры самым адекватным советом является слепой метод печати(который для иностранца так же важен, как для программиста английский) и распечатка раскладки перед глазами. По крайней мере, вы лишитесь множества проблем при общении с не говорящими на английском языке людьми. У меня вообще клавиатура с черными кнопками, мне это не мешает.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0hCMZ.png

Answer (score 21):

## О недостаточно активном написании ответов

Не понимаю, где вы видите проблему недостатка ответов. Абсолютное большинство вопросов, которые написаны вменяемо и по сколь-нибудь популярной тематике — ответы имеют. Посмотрите на [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) — ответы даны практически в 100% случаев, часто в течение 5-10 минут, за возможность быть первым постоянное соревнование. Если нет ответа, то или вопрос заминусован за низкое качество (как правило, настолько низкое, что ответ при всём желании дать нельзя, потому что в достатке заминусованных вопросов с ответами), или вопрос закрыт, или в комментариях прошло вразумительное обсуждение.

Да, есть вопросы по редким тематикам: редким языкам, редким библиотекам. Но и отвечать на них некому. Если я не разбираюсь в вопросе, то я, конечно, могу через гугл наковырять ответ для простенького вопроса, но мои возможности ограничены.

Если вы считаете, что какой-то хороший вопрос, на который сообщество в состоянии ответить, незаслуженно проигнорирован, то объявите конкурс в конце концов. Всё в ваших собственных руках.

## О тегах на старых и новых вопросах

Если вам совершенно наплевать, что появляются новые вопросы с тегом [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и прочими бессмысленными тегами, то спешу вас разочаровать: не все с вами согласны. Я хочу видеть качественные теги и на старых, и на новых вопросах.

Плохие теги на старых вопросах — это не только ископаемый артефакт, но и прямое следствие того, что на *новых* вопросах появляются бессмысленные теги. Единственная возможность запретить тег для использования новичками, не прибегая к запросам напрямую к базе — это удалить все использования тега. Уж такой движок.

У простых ромбовых модераторов возможности массово менять теги сильно ограничены: нельзя удалить тег из всех вопросов, нельзя запретить тег, нельзя разделить тег и так далее. Можно только орудовать над синонимами разными способами, что никак не помогает в задаче избавления от мета-тегов.

## О главной странице

Масштаб страданий от заполнения главной страницы сильно преувеличен. На сайте существуют десятки способов следить за последними обновлениями, и главная страница — далеко не самый удобный инструмент. Там даже текст вопроса не показывается! Как этим вообще пользоваться можно?

Уж вам, как опытному пользователю, точно грешно жаловаться на заполнение главной страницы. Как показывают опросы, топовые юзеры на СО этой страницей практически не пользуются, предпочитая более точные и удобные инструменты. Не буду вас учить — уверен, что вы сами прекрасно знаете, как искать вопросы на СО.

## Об ответах на старые вопросы

Что появится штук пять ответов на старые вопросы от новичков, которые не смотрят на даты — в этом ничего дурного нет. Неправильные теги бывают и у хороших вопросов, поэтому это лишь хороший повод получить значок "Некромант" или "Возрождение".

Написание ответов для старых вопросов наоборот приветствуется. Учитывая, что у нас далеко не лучшая статистика по вопросам без ответов — всего лишь 74%, примерно как и на большом СО, то появление хороших ответов на старые вопросы — это замечательно.

Более того, на сайте есть инструменты для слежения за ответами на старые вопросы. Во-первых, это очередь проверок "Запоздалые ответы". Там можно заплюсовать, заминусовать, удалить и откомментировать ответы на старые вопросы. Во-вторых, на вкладке инструментов модераторов, которая доступна для всех, у кого есть 2К репы, есть возможность следить за запоздалыми ответами ото всех пользователей, а не только от новичков.

## О минусах и закрытиях

Если человек неспособен адекватно воспринимать минусы и закрытие вопросов, и вместо коррекции своих действий убегает с воплями — я не хочу видеть этого пользователя на сайте. Человек должен уметь читать правила и следовать им, адекватно воспринимать критику и корректировать действия. Не может — скатертью дорога.

Я уже раз десять об этом писал, но повторюсь ещё раз: закрытие вопросов и минусы — это *инструмент*, а не приговор. Если вопрос исправлен, то он будет очень быстро открыт. А закрывать важно, чтобы не стимулировать написание ответов на некачественные вопросы.

Нужно стимулировать правильное поведение, иначе сайт обрастёт аудиторией help vampires, которые ничего не хотят делать сами, и при первой вылетевшей ошибке копипастят её в поле для вопроса. Я не хочу, чтобы аудитория на сайте состояла из таких чуть менее, чем полностью. И поэтому я буду "обижать" новичков закрытием некачественных вопросов.

## О закрытии старых вопросов

И это, как ни странно, тоже важно.

Когда на сайт приходит новичок, он смотрит, какие вопросы задаются, как они задаются. Важно, чтобы он видел качественные вопросы и ответы, а не древний некачественный хлам, потому что новичок будет действовать по образу и подобию.

Когда на сайт приходит профессионал, он тоже смотрит на вопросы. И если он видит флуд, оффтопик, пространные рассуждения и прочее — он просто уходит. И это **огромная ужасная проблема**. Профессионалов мало, и именно их надо ценить и следить, чтобы им на сайте хорошо жилось. Именно они — самая большая ценность сайта, а не мириады новичков, поток которых никогда не иссякает.

Вы видели обсуждение на Хабре, пока его не снесли? Там все кому не лень писали, что здесь ловить нечего. Так давайте докажем обратное, а не будем усугублять положение!

Право вытирать сопли новичкам, которые два слова сложить не могут — это я оставлю кому-нибудь другому. А сам я предпочитаю помогать тем, кто может задавать качественные вопросы и может давать качественные ответы. Поэтому гуглением ответов на вопрос "Как сделать X в Y с помощью PHP/JS" пусть лучше занимаются другие, я своё время могу потратить с большей пользой (впрочем, от скуки могу и на такие вопросы ответить).

## Последнее слово

Поверьте, если бы я видел в списке новых вопросов те, на которые могу ответить, я бы не занимался систематизацией и организацией, а отвечал бы на них. Но таких вопросов мало, и кончаются они быстро.

Так что, уж извините, я буду делать то, что, как мне видится, приносит пользу сайту — вместо того, чтобы не делать абсолютно ничего.

Comment: offtop: [уничтожение меток "без суда и следствия" ;) -- это отработанная система на большом SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-system)

Comment: (1) По поводу популярной тематики: на текущий момент на главной 16 вопросов по Java (12 имеют ответы), 7 по PHP (2 имеют ответы), 5 по C++ (3 с ответами), 3 по C# (2 с ответами). Вопросов по wpf вовсе нет. Так что «практически 100%» — это далеко не везде и не всегда.

Comment: (2) Точная расстановка тегов никого не волнует в пределах экспериментальной погрешности. Никто вообще не страдает от наличия лишнего тега. Доставить недостающий тег имеет ещё какую-то академическую ценность. (3) Вопрос не упоминает главную. О чём вы?

Comment: (4) Я искренне рад, что когда я впервые появился на сайте, ко мне не применялись жёсткие критерии. Мне хочется верить, что большинство на сайте — за политику, включающую пряник, а не только кнут. (5) Среднестатистический пользователь вряд ли вдумчиво читает старые вопросы. Профессионал гораздо больше обращает внимания на текущие вопросы, чем на археологию. Если, конечно, старые вопросы не висят постоянно на виду.

Comment: (6) Я не думал, что смогу переубедить _всех_. Я лишь надеюсь, что часть пользователей сайта услышит меня. Думаю, вы не в обиде на меня за то, что и я действую так, как мне кажется правильным.

Comment: @VladD (1) Смотреть надо не на главную, которая отображает чёрт знает что, а на вторую страницу ответов (№№50–99) по конкретным тегам при сортировке по дате. Это более точно отражает, какие вопросы получают ответы. На вопросы по PHP, как вы догадываетесь, мне глубоко пофиг. (2) Посчитайте количество голосов у темы "Долой [программирование]!" Даже мелкая тема про языки набрала плюсы. (3) Вы возмущались в чате, решил раскрыть тему, раз уж подвернулся случай. (4) Пряник для тех, кто демонстрирует желание и способность учиться, а не для всех посетителей.

Comment: @VladD (6) Пока что ваши действия в основном ограничиваются высказыванием мнения на Мете и в чате. Против этого я никак не могу быть. Если вы протолкнёте радикальные изменения в политике, я, конечно, буду против, но пока что я не верю в успех этого предприятия и поэтому не заморачиваюсь. :) Что вы начнёте голосовать как Qwertiy из чувства протеста — я тоже не верю. Так что в целом — успехов. :)

Comment: (1) С таким отношением (PHP пофиг) сайт бы не взлетел. (2) Угу, и что? И сколько людей после этого пошли в крестовый поход на все остальные теги? Ваш аргумент слаб. (3) Офтопик. (4) А вот про это и мой ОП. О том, что с таким отношением на сайте останутся два человека. (6) Взаимно.

Comment: @VladD (1) К счастью, не отвечаю за влёт сайта. :) Если вы беспокоитесь за малый процент отвеченных вопросов по PHP, можете приниматься за изучение языка и всего зоопарка библиотек, фреймворков и CMS для него. :) (2) Ладно, убедили, буду уничтожать [программирование]. Если что, сами напросились. :) (4) Очевидно, что вы преувеличиваете. Закрывашек у нас на сайте предостаточно, вопросы закрываются и минусуются, а новых пользователей только больше.

Comment: @Athari: (1) Это, не воспримите за критику, видно. (2) Смешная шутка. (4) А многие ли из них остаются? Ну выгоните вы старую гвардию, будет лучше, да?

Comment: @VladD (4) Кто эта старая гвардия, которая боится закрывания вопросов? Ну покажите пальцем что ли. Если представитель старой гвардии любит только пофлудить — скатертью дорога. Если умеет писать хорошие вопросы и ответы — скорее всего, сможет адаптироваться к новой среде. Изменения не настолько катастрофические. Пока я не наблюдаю проблемы. / К слову, я не наблюдаю заоблачного рейтинга у этого вопроса.

Comment: @Athari: Они здесь больше не появляются в основном, да. Вам, понятно, старая гвардия пофиг. Вам и сайт пофиг, как вы говорили выше. Я обращался к тем, кому не пофиг. / "Я скакала за вами 3 дня, чтобы сказать, как вы мне безразличны!" (ц)

Comment: @VladD, а Вы знаете действительные причины, почему т.н. "Старая гвардия" больше не появляется? Ведь если это лишь из-за того, что SO противоречит стилю форумной болтовни(а на форумах для этого всегда были отдельные разделы, которые не мешали основным), а им эта болтовня жизненно необходима. тогда может и ну их? Нет, я серьёзно, терять людей знающих всегда плохо, но ресурс должен стать профессиональным или он нафиг не нужен.

Comment: @ixSci: Я лишь строю предположения, люди иногда приходят и уходят и сами по себе. Форумной болтовни не было и на ХК, насколько я помню. (Это было, в частности, из-за жёсткого ограничения в 4 (!) комментария на человека в вопросе.) Мне кажется, мы ещё не раскрутились до того уровня, когда можем отпугивать людей. Тут вопрос становления, а не перфекционизма.

Comment: полностью разделяю данную точку зрения.

Comment: @Athari: давайте опираться на факты, а не личные впечатления: [area51 говорит, что не достаточно ответов на русском SO](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian). Если в ваших активных метках ситуация лучше, то подтвердите это данными (благо data.stackexchange есть).

Comment: @jfs http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/313090/tags-stats — по C# и C++ лучшая статистика (92-95% вопросов с ответами, 78-82% с принятыми/заплюсованными ответами). Сравните со статистикой большого СО http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/313090/tags-stats

Comment: @Athari: только принятые/заплюсованные ответы имеют значение. В данный момент процент ответов совпадает с большим SO (74%) -- это мало для бета-сайтов (по меркам area51). Поэтому довод может быть только, что мы сами с усами и слово beta на экране, к нам не относится.

Comment: @jfs Что ответы не плюсуются и не принимаются — это плохо. Но со стороны отвечающих на это сложно повлиять, потому что от качества ответа не всё зависит. Тут скорее можно списать на то, что программирование — это очень обширная тематика (нехаратерно для бет сайтов SE) и огромное количество слабых новичков. Уж так сложилось. В этих условиях ответы по обсуждаемым тегам даны на все вопросы, на которые сообщество в состоянии ответить. Никто не лодырничает. Вообще, эта статистика по "unanswered" — не более, чем абстрактный ориентир, а не какое-то жёсткое требование.

Comment: Масштаб страданий от того, что появляются новые вопросы с тегом программирование, сильно преувеличен. Если вам совершенно наплевать, что появляется на главной странице, то спешу вас разочаровать: не все с вами согласны.

Comment: @Etki Если у вопроса только теги "программирование" и "веб-программирование", то это таки доставляет ощутимые неудобства. А если у тега 10 способов написания, то это таки доставляет ощутимые неудобства при поиске. А гугл не умеет ни делать чёткие запросы по тегам, ни сортировать по разным признакам.

Comment: Ох. Это мой способ сказать "в аргументации следует избегать эмоциональных конструкций, потому что они не только не являются аргументами, но и легко обращаются вспять".

Comment: @Etki Я понял. Но страдания от неправильных меток я оцениваю как более сильные, чем от испорченной главной страницы — довольно неудобного инструмента. :)

Comment: На Хабрахабре хаяли этот сайт? Доброе знамение. Туземцы по-моему вообще любят хаять всё, что выше их уровня.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Нужно не унижать пользователей другого сайта (очень успешного и временами полезного, надо заметить), а прислушиваться к критике, даже если она высказана не самым деликатным способом. На Хабре верно подметили реальные проблемы проекта.

Comment: @Discord: и в самом успешном сообществе водятся отбросы (в каких-то количествах), а в Содоме можно найти одного праведника. Охота Вам пропускать поток ерунды через мощный фильтр дабы выловить разумный остаток? Ну Вы молодец.

Answer (score 16):

В рунете давно проблема со специалистами, которые желают участвовать в генерации русскоязычного содержания. Куда не плюнь, в рунете темы, в основном, только для новичков. Поэтому ожидать, что сюда сразу набежит куча спецов - наивно. И я уверен, что если данный сайт не станет рассматривать сложные вопросы и безжалостно выпиливать всякий ширпотреб, то мы этих спецов и не увидим.

Старожилы hashcode не приходят из-за атмосферы? Я, разумеется, не знаю, что там была за такая особенная атмосфера и почему их не устраивает новая, но есть обычная житейская ситуация, когда "цари и боги" одной группы людей, попадают в другую группу, где они больше не "цари и боги" их это раздражает и они прекращают посещать новую группу. Это вполне нормальная ситуация, которая сплошь и рядом встречается в человеческой жизни. С этим ничего не поделать.

Кроме того, а был ли hashcode популярен? Было ли там действительно лучше? А может hashcode с подобной "либеральной" политикой шёл в ту же мусорку, куда ушли QA хабра, да и сам хабр? А может именно жёсткость сделал SO тем, чем является сейчас?

В общем, я против ненужной мягкости. Здоровая жёсткость ещё никогда не мешала.

Comment: К месту будет вспомнить историю сайта *Not Programming Related*. Сайт появился из Зоны 51 много позже Stack Overflow, когда на последнем уже проводились постоянные "репрессии", и народу хотелось свободного общения "как на старом Stack Overflow". Сайт был создан. И очень быстро превратился в отстойную яму. Туда сваливался весь хлам со всех сайтов, количество активных юзеров всё уменьшалось, костяк составляла маленькая группа юзеров. В какой-то момент стало ясно, что дальше так жить нельзя, что это тупик. Тогда *NPR* был полностью переосмыслен и превратился в *Programmers*.

Comment: Я и не ожидаю этого. Я говорю скорее о создании _атмосферы_, комфортной для адекватных людей.

Comment: @VladD, можете описать видимую Вами атмосферу подробнее и что предлагается делать всем, для её достижения. Из оригинального вопроса я этого, к сожалению, не понял.

Comment: Ух, вопросики. Мне кажется, сайт стал более злым и нетерпимым к вполне простительным ошибкам новичков. Что именно предлагается делать — и есть тема опроса (посмотрите последнюю строку).

Comment: @ixSci, раньше все говорили друг другу "Здраствуйте"; просили совета, куда пойти учиться; помогали студентам делать домашки по доброте душевной, даже зная, что это нехорошо.

Comment: Я бы сказал так про старую атмосферу. Представьте, что за каждый поставленный минус, закрытие по несоответствующей теме или не данное перед закрытием предупреждение о причине, Вы начинаете расплачиваться своим собственным рейтингом. В этом случае Вы уже десять раз подумаете, а действительно ли этот вопрос настолько плох, что автор уже не сможет его исправить или нормально дополнить если помочь ему и мне не жалко влепить минус за написанное.

Comment: @Discord ZOMGþedrama! Будьте любезны прямую ссылку на обсуждение этого «переосмысления».

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Подозреваю, переосмысление размазано ровным слоем по соответствующей мете. Изменение произошло не единоминутно.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд (сравнительно нового) пользователя StackExchange, на данный момент острой проблемы некачественных вопросов на ru.stackoverflow нет. Но есть намёк на синдром, характерный для «сайтов шпаны»: не вполне адекватная (на мой взгляд) **оценка вопросов** сообществом.

Вот вопрос: [Как определить не русский текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432824/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)
Был на −1, когда я пришёл, [подвергся редактированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/432824/revisions), якобы ввиду малограмотности, и комментарии забиты всякими хихи-хаха. Но основная задача в теле вопроса была сформулирована вполне чётко.

- Была ли малограмотность? Я бы не сказал, т. к. слово [«нерусский» (без пробела)](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) существует.
- Был ли серьёзный недостаток? Да, кривость формулировки заглавия.
- Был ли редактированием вопроса *исправлен* этот недостаток? Нет, только  добавлены пробелы и перенесены в тело куски комментариев.

Т. е. что мы видим? Вопрос отредактировали, главный его недостаток при этом не исправив, а затем минуснули.
Притом, что задача вполне себе практическая.

Ну а где [искать примеры *переоценённых* вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes&pageSize=96), думаю, вы бы и без меня догадались.

Таких крайностей, как [самодурство обленившихся «экспертов» на ServerFault](http://www.superstructure.info/StackExchange/serverfault/domain-s-ns-accessible-via-ipv6-only.html) или [полоумная стадность physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/56960/), тут конечно не назревает. Но хотелось бы видеть, чтобы толковые активные участники ru.SO оказывали авторам приличных вопросов поддержку хотя бы в форме **▲**, систематически. Меньше думаем о luser’ах. Больше думаем о перспективных участниках, которых равнодушие истэблишмента может оттолкнуть.

Comment: Авторам приличных вопросов оказывается ровно столько внимания, сколько они заслуживают. Авторам неприличных вопросов - тоже. Хотите оказывать поддержку "приличным" вопросам и ответам - используйте свои голоса. А остальным позвольте самим решать, на каких вопросах и ответах мне нажимать +, а на каких - минус.

Comment: А по поводу вопроса про нерусские символы - недостаток там совсем не в кривой формулировке заглавия. А в нехватке деталей - что видно по комментам. Nick перенес ваш коммент в тело вопроса - и этим немного его улучшил. Если вам не нравится какая-то правка, вы, как автор вопроса, можете ее откатить, в один клик.

Comment: Кажется, у @PashaPash возникла путаница между неким вопросом о нерусских символах и похождениями некого Incnis Mrsi на иных сайтах StackExchange. Ну это не страшно; со временем привыкнет одно от другого отличать.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Ну ладно вам переходить на личности. Мы же здесь все хотим сделать сайт лучше, правильно? Давайте не ссориться.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: А вопрос, на который вы ссылаетесь, и правда не очень. «Нерусские символы» и правда очень нечёткое определение. Может быть, вы подберёте ещё пример, чтобы проиллюстрировать вашу идею?

Comment: У вас ссылка "serverfault" ведёт на какой-то странный сайт.

Comment: @Ivan Solntsev: потому, что я обиделся, и изуродовал (defaced) исходный вопрос. Ну если у них вопрос о работе name-серверов *too opinion-based*, то что ещё сказать? По ссылке показано то, что было в теме непосредственно перед тем, как я хлопнул дверью.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi В вашем сетевом профиле нет ни одного сайта с > 1000 репутации. Именно поэтому я перепутал вас с автором вопроса про нерусские символы - тут достаточно часто новички заводят по несколько профилей (обычно случайно).

Comment: @VladD: У меня возникло впечатление (скорее интуиция опытного интернетчика, чем тщательный анализ), что в ru.SO многовато придирок не по делу. Завтра я возражу и на Ваше возражение, и попробую поискать менее спорные примеры.

Comment: @PashaPash: В вашем сетевом профиле нет ни одного английского сайта с ≥ 1626 репутации. Странно, но эта важнейшая информация не позволяет мне сделать вывод об уровне владения англ.языком и т.п.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: С этим я согласен, но мне кажется, что ситуация со временем немного улучшается.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi да, репутация на enSO у меня почти никакая, поэтому я не создаю посты на enSO meta, с советами "за что вам голосовать, а за что - нет. кстати, на SF и Phys все козлы". Система репутации enSO поощеряет минусование плохих вопросов. На минусы завязаны механизмы чистки/удаления. Хотите чтобы вопросы от новичков плюсовались - правьте их и пишите нормальные ответы. А не "возражайте на возражения" на мете.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, ваш вандализм откатили в течение получаса, а все правки доступны в истории ревизий. http://serverfault.com/posts/686202/revisions вопрос действительно не соотвествует стандартам сообщества, тем не менее вы получили 2 подробных ответа.

Comment: А ссылка про полоумную стадность ведет на вашу собственную страницу на physics. Где там искать иллюстрацию стадности?

Comment: @Ivan Solntsev: «не соответствует стандартам» потому, что у большинства обретающихся там весёлых мальчиков отсутствуют знания, потребные для *ответа* с соблюдением стандартов StackExchange.
Вот они, во избежание флейма, вопрос закрыли и вовсе.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi у большинства "веселых мальчиков", закрывших ваш вопрос, уровень знаний намного превышает демонстрируемый вами (под демонстрацией я подразумеваю именно вклад в community, в виде хороших ответов или вопросов). Если у вас недостаточно развита самокритика, чтобы понять настоящую причину закрытия (а она подробно разжевана в комментариях к вашему вопросу) - это ваша проблема. Уже сам по себе ваш ответ не по теме, с "сайты для шпаны", "переоцененные вопросы", "самодурство" и "полоумная стадность" тянет на злостный умышленный офтопик и бан. Я удивляюсь терпению модераторов.