# 300 спартанцев (загнивает ли ruSO)?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, stackoverflow

Как-то случайно я посмотрел на [5-ю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?page=5&tab=reputation&filter=year) страницу сортировки по репутации за год, и что я увидел… В ходе несложных вычислений я обнаружил, что на ruSO всего 165<sup>1</sup> пользователей, имеющих прирост репы (за год) больше 1к (т. е. 2 лайка в неделю, и 1к реп/год в кармане) (конечно, и тут есть исключения по типу [Николая Семенова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/333174/%d0%9d%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2?tab=topactivity) — абсолютный рекордсмен по убыткам, хотя парень старается). **Нас всего 165!** Это даже меньше, чем 300 спартанцев.

Не знаю, насколько порог в 1к реп/год объективен и полезен, но факт остаётся фактом: нас всего 0,08% (165 из 205 792) от кол-ва всех пользователей. Эта проблема была ещё подмечена [Владом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-so-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-so) 5 лет тому назад.

По этому поводу есть несколько вопросов:

- **Загнивает ли ruSO?** Плохо ли, что огромное кол-во пользователей с кол-вом репы больше 1к покинули нас, и такой же прирост за год наблюдается только у 165 человек?
- **Что дальше?** Я не знаю, как выглядят графики кол-ва пользователей с более чем 1к реп и кол-ва пользователей с более чем 1к реп, покинувших нас. Если бы я это знал, то можно было бы проследить тренды увеличения и уменьшения числа постоянных пользователей и однозначно определить, всё ли в порядке. Но т. к. такой информацией я не владею, остаётся только разводить дискуссии по этому поводу.
- **Бежать? и куда?** Стоит ли бежать на enSO, Тостер, <s>Хешкод</s>, или куда-нибудь ещё, вести параллельную деятельность, глядя на такую статистику; возможно стоит вести какую-то работу по улучшению статистики, или ваш вариант?

Будет интересно посмотреть *ваше мнение* по этому поводу.

---

<sup>1</sup> Информация в вопросе была взята на момент 25 сен 2020 г.

Comment: Подобные темы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4770/213987 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8948/213987

Comment: @AK Там было субъективное мнение авторов вопросов, здесь же статистика: 165 активных юзеров на весь ruSO. Это я так от дубликата страхуюсь (зн. что вы снялись с поста).

Comment: Моё мнение, что "вечные темы" не стоит закрывать дублями, а просто обсуждать современное состояние тем. Так что не закрыл бы, просто слинковал в правое меню темы. Запрос кстати не обязательно было смотреть на dataSE или мотать страницы: есть зал славы за месяц/квартал/год. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/609/year/ru-stackoverflow там те же цифры

Comment: Чтобы быть менее субъективным, вам стоило бы все же провести анализ и сравнение. 165  это мало или много, почему вы считает что мало?

Comment: Про абсолютного рекордсмена по убыткам я бы поспорил :) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10556/398802

Comment: @Kromster Нет, я не считаю, что абсолютное число — это мало. Я же привёл там относительное число в процентах. От него и нужно отталкиваться

Comment: @dIm0n Этот вопрос я читал :) Конечно, это [ваше замечание] вырвано из контекста (там я говорил про годовое снятие репутации), но это не главное (:

Comment: @return Многие недовольны модерацией))) Я вот жду.

Comment: @return, разделяю вашу озабоченность. Хорошо бы понять причины, что отталкивают программистов от ответов на вопросы тут.

Comment: То что вы привели процент, не говорит о том, мал он или велик. Надо с чем-то сравнивать. 0.08% соли в супе - это одно, ДДТ в почве - другое, миллиардеров в стране - третье.

Comment: @Kromster возможно, нужно сравнивать с enSO. Братья по цеху как никак.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Мод.состав объновился, вы не заметили?

Comment: @0xdb Приветствую Вас. Рад видеть. Подскажите, пожалуйста, я что-то пропустил?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Не знаю, пропустили или нет. Вроде выборы были и мод-состав изменился. Или вас модерация в целом не устраивала, а не кто-то лично?

Comment: @0xdb Suvitruf. Вы же помните наверно?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Он и AK подали в отставку, поэтому и выборы были.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо за информацию. Надо возвращаться на stackover уиии )

Comment: @Denis640Kb Да, конечно возвращайтесь. Правда, принципы работы ресурса не изменились (ведь Вы и с ними были оплностью согласны, как помню).

Comment: @Denis640Kb Вы пропустили 3 крупных события: [пони](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc), [уход](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10777/) Suvitruf с AK, новые выборы.

Comment: То чувство когда тебя записали в спартанцы, а ты как был тупенький, так и остался =)

Comment: 300 спартанцев не могут ответить на элеменетарнейший вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1187934/16825

Comment: @hellboy вполне возможно, что спартанцам не хочется отвечать на вопрос, потому что он "элементарный". я на него не отвечу, т.к. я шарпист ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Он не "элементарный". Этот баг висит у нас уже 3 года

Answer (score 30):

Активный прирост репутации в основном у отвечающих. Чтобы человек много и регулярно отвечал, нужны мотивы:

- Вопросы должны быть интересными;
- Этот труд должен цениться администрацией;
- Репутация должна приносить какую-то выгоду.

По всем пунктам у ruSO есть проблемы.

- Интересные вопросы - это крупицы в бурном потоке просьб сделать домашку от пользователей-однодневок.
- Мнение топов ничего не значит, к их удерживанию на ресурсе не прикладывается ни малейших усилий.
- На большом SO и у Тостера есть механизмы привлечения работодателей, на ruSO их нет.

Comment: Сергей, вы ещё связаны с тостером? Не буду спрашивать про выгоду репутации на en so, а какую выгоду приносит репутация на тостере? Мне кажется, что в этом плане разницы между ru so и тостером нет.

Comment: @AK да, всё ещё связан, но предвзятости это не формирует. У бывшего Тостера, ныне Хабр Q&A, интеграция с Хабр Карьерой, через которую в последнее время ко мне идёт большой поток предложений.

Answer (score 23):

вот, кстати, первый раз напишу ответ на мету.

я тут со времён хэшкода и у меня нет и никогда не было прироста в 1к в год. так что по-вашему выходит что я - один из тех, кто делает ru.so болотцем. хотя на самом деле ваша гипотеза непростительно проще реальности, которую пытается формализовать.

у меня нет прироста в 1к т.к. мне не интересно отвечать на вопросы которые щёлкают Igor, OPTIMUS PRIME или Vasily, но и такого таланта как у Мелкого и Akina из [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) у меня нет :)

кроме этого, меня серьёзно демотивирует кейс когда [дурацкий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171088/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-filter-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-0/1171093#1171093) ответ набирает 7 баллов (потому что его прощёлкал каждый, кому ответ понятен), а [интересный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1179288/nodejs-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-fs/1179326#1179326) [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1178589/2659) набирает 2.

так что... у меня лапки.

*Загнивает ли ruSO?*

не-а, всегда так было.

*Что дальше?*

простых вопросов станет больше. учебных заданий станет больше (надо завести для них отдельный so и отвечать в лучших традициях Grundy).

тут комфортно и иногда интересно. я останусь.

Comment: Плюсую. Но ответ написан "в лучших традициях" @aleksandr barakin ;)

Answer (score 9):

Ненароком заметил пост [200 вопросов в день!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5030/176217) (даже несколько гармонирует с названием текущей темы). Если посмотреть на дату его создания, то прошло уже **3 года** с небольшим. А взглянув снова на [таблицу статистики](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday) сайтов, можно заметить, что ruSO по этому показателю топчется на месте.

> [image: Вопросов в день]

Прогресса в скорости прибавления вопросов в день не наблюдается. Кто-то может быть это даже назовёт деградацией, но 200 vs 193 - это, по моему мнению, одно и то же в качественном плане.

Справедливости ради можно сравнить и другие сайты из топа (было - стало):

```
------------- вопросы ------------- посещения -----------
enSO        8700 - 6900           10000k - 11000k 
Mathematics  618 -  530             256k - 290k
ruSO         200 -  193              64k - 86k
Super User   148 -  116             677k - 699k  
Ask Ubuntu   164 -  115             595k - 411k
```

Вопросов задаётся меньше, но посещаемость растёт (Ask Ubuntu, правда, совсем сдал по этому показателю). Для владельцев сайта, я думаю, показатель посещаемости более важен, чем новые вопросы, чего нельзя сказать о людях, которые приходят сюда, чтобы вносить свой вклад, наполняя базу знаний. Поэтому мы и воспринимаем это как упадок ruSO.

Answer (score 8):

У нас довольно маленькое сообщество по сравнению с en.SO например. Но маленьнькое — не значит плохое, и это довольно относительное понятие. Никуда бежать не надо, просто участвуйте и все. В одно вермя больше людей, в другое меньше. Некоторые активные участники могут не иметь никакого прироста из-за странной привычки писать ответы в комменты (@andreymal). Некоторые люди набирают репу и "сливают" на конкурсы, снова набирают, снова "сливают" (@dIm0n).

- > Загнивает ли ruSO? Плохо ли, что огромное кол-во пользователей с кол-вом репы больше 1к покинули нас, и такой же прирост за год наблюдается только у 165 человек.

  Все нормально, сравнитесь хоть с conlang.SE ;)
- > Что дальше? Я не знаю, как выглядят графики кол-ва пользователей с более чем 1к реп и кол-ва пользователей с более чем 1к реп, покинувших нас. Если бы я это знал, то можно было бы проследить тренды увеличения и уменьшения числа постоянных пользователей и однозначно определить, всё ли в порядке. Но т. к. такой информацией я не владею, остаётся только разводить дискуссии по этому поводу.

  data.SE — ответы на все такие вопросы
- > Бежать? и куда? Стоит ли бежать на enSO, Тостер, Хешкод, или куда-нибудь ещё, вести параллельную деятельность, глядя на такую статистику; возможно стоит вести какую-то работу по улучшению статистики, или ваш вариант?

  Зачем??? ;) Это наше сообщество и его развитие зависит в том числе от нас.

Comment: Я имел ввиду именно процентное соотношение. 0,08% кажется довольно маленьким числом.

Comment: @return И что? ;)

Comment: непоколебимо (мало символов)

Comment: @return непоколебимо что?

Comment: Ваша позиция. Я имел ввиду именно это.

Comment: Я dataSE не пользовался до этого, следовательно, не могу посмотреть нормально прирост репы. Может есть способы попроще?

Comment: @return Потом как-нибудь напишу, ща чуть-чуть занят ;)

Comment: @return https://stackexchange.com/leagues/609/year/ru-stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

Должен признаться, я сюда только вопросы пишу. Я правда читаю иногда вопросы, но они такие тяжелые, а на легких меня всегда обгоняют. Но, во-первых, это же тоже нужно, во-вторых, если найду ответ, то всегда отписываюсь. Но могу не отписаться, если мне вообще ничего не напишут. А вообще, всё не так уж плохо, люди всё же пытаются помочь, чащё кто-то что-то пишет, чем нет.

Answer (score 5):

Пришел сюда совсем зеленым в 2015 году, еще когда учился в университете - по совету аспиранта. Аспирант тогда у нас принимал практику по C++ и я его пытал разными вопросами. Ну он и отправил меня на SO.

Задавал вопросы, задавал. Некоторое время даже удавалось отвечать. Иногда даже не заходил по пол года - год. Сейчас решил отдать долг. Мне отвечали и отвечали хорошо! Особенно KoVadim и VladD. Так что сижу в свободное от работы время и отвечаю. Проверяю очереди на правки и прочее. Иногда отвечаю на уже отвеченные вопросы, просто потому что имеется другой вариант решения. Беру простые вопросы, так как боюсь браться за более сложные, пока не хватает опыта отвечать со скоростью самой быстрой руки дикого запада.

Так что думаю в первую очередь - развитие RuSO это новые пользователи, может быть они тоже потом вернуться и будут пытаться отвечать.

Не загнивает RuSO. Просто некоторые либо находят ответ на EnSO, либо идут за вопросом туда. Я слышал пару раз от коллег примерно следующее - "лучше спрашивать на EnSO чем на RuSO". Не знаю почему у них сложилось такое мнение. Может быть просто потому что EnSO старше, там многие именитые люди (тот же самый Джон Скит и прочие MVP microsoft)

Answer (score 4):

Результаты зависят от политики, а политика зависит от целей. Если главная цель состоит в том, чтобы привлечь как можно больше пользователей, то нужно привлекать пользователей, которым нужно решить домашку -- таких желающих очень много. Нужно решать за них домашку, и они будут приходить снова и снова и приводить за собой толпы последователей. А чтобы не переводились решальщики домашек, нужно плюсовать решения -- это очень хорошо стимулирует тщеславие, которое является мощным мотиватором. Причем это процесс с положительной обратной связью -- его не надо стимулировать, он развивается сам собой -- всякий нашедший решение своей домашки поставит плюс, и у решальщика появится дополнительная мотивация. И неважно, что решальщик не всегда свои мысли способен ясно сформулировать, и решение далеко не оптимально -- это процессу не помешает, поскольку бОльшая часть такой аудитории качеством не интересуется и оценить его редко способна. Минус у такой политики только один -- программистам (не студентам) это редко бывает интересно. Доля людей, способных ответить на сложные и интересные вопросы, будет сокращаться, соответственно будет убывать надежда получить ответ на сложный вопрос, а с ней будет убывать и количество таких вопросов. Опять процесс с положительной обратной связью.

Мне кажется, в этом причина того, что количество людей, способных грамотно ответить на сложные вопросы, здесь не так велико, как хотелось бы, а если и есть такие люди, они нечасто сюда заглядывают.

Comment: Какие будут конкретные предложения, что именно по вашему надо изменить для улучшения ситуации?

Comment: @avp Ну я думаю для начала стоило бы решить, нужно ли вообще что-то улучшать. Я не уверен. Мне кажется, бОльшую часть участников, так же как администрацию и модераторов, всё устраивает, а кого что-то не устраивало, те просто сюда не заходят, или заходят лишь изредка, чтобы развеяться, отдохнуть, и может быть сделать какое-нибудь несложное упражнение. Я не знаю, что думают другие, но если всех всё устраивает, то и говорить не о чем.

Comment: Не интересно тут стало после массированной ориентации на "базу знаний". Раньше в комментариях горячие обсуждения бывали. Теперь это пресекли, толком что-нибудь обсудить стало не с кем. Захожу, скорее по привычке. Наверное вы правы, пора завязывать с этим болотом.

Comment: @avp для "обсуждений" в рунете форумов хоть завались - можно на любой пойти (даже не по теме). А вот нормальной Базы Знаний, без тонн флуда и воды - не сыскать. Как, кстати, SOпротивление не создало еще аналога SO, но с теплотой и ламповостью?

Comment: @Kromster, а кто же по вашему эту мифическую «базу знаний» будет наполнять, если всех разогнать? Лично мне особенно обидно за C/C++ разделы. Примерно в одно и тоже время, в конце 19 года перестали проявлять активность такие пользователи как AnT, Abyx, ixSci. У некоторых в профиле явно сказано, что ушли, т.к. их комментарии не нравятся администрации ресурса. Эти товарищи могли написать ответы на некоторые очень узкоспециализированные темы, причём с пруфами на стандарты. Сейчас такие вопросы просто останутся без ответа, либо ограничатся комментарием вида «ну, так написано в стандарте». Обидно.

Comment: @wololo начали со "straw man argument" - приписали мне то, чего я не говорил. Люди приходят, люди уходят - это нормально. Если комментарии не нравятся администрации ресурса, то наверное с ними все же что-то не так (кстати, комментарии не предназначены для расширенных дискуссий). Ну и сослагательное наклонение в конце .. Мне кажется таких обсуждений на ruSO и не нужно )

Answer (score 2):

Я совсем зеленый в so. Опубликовал пару вопросов и ответов, которые искал на en SO. Спросил, что подобная генерация контента норм)) но сложно понять, насколько это полезно.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вообще все загнивает.
2. Дальше прозябание, тлен, забвение.
3. Бежать некуда. Даже марсианская экспедиция Маска не выход.

Вспомните тот же ЖЖ пятнадцать лет назад и посмотрите, где он сейчас.

Суета, деградация и энтропия — вот и все, что когда-либо было на этой планете, как и на любой другой.

Comment: Надо валить. Осталось понять - куда, когда или кого... :)

Comment: enSO, кстати, не опция, со всеми мониками и регулярными новыми этическими кодексами.

Comment: @Harry, зачем, все бесполезно! Завалишь одного — на его место придут девять других. Только спрыгнуть с колеса сансары, только хардкор!

Comment: за "монками" да еще с маленькой буквы можно и в `''.join(map(chr, [1073, 1091, 1073, 1077, 1085, 32, 1087, 1086, 1083, 1091, 1095, 1080, 1090, 1100]))`
  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Всё не так плохо.

1. Да, `165` отвечающих это мало, и этого числа не хватит, чтобы ответить на все вопросы. Но всё-таки на март `2023` года у нас `345875` (!!! триста сорок пять тысяч восемьсот семьдесят пять)
   вопросов, на которые дан хотя бы один ответ. Я считаю, что это уже хорошо.
2. Иногда новые отвечающие (не `chatGPT`-шники, а нормальные) всё-же появляются. Один из таких - я `=)`
3. Конкретно с проблемой малого количества отвечающих вряд ли можно что-то сделать. Но я рекомендую вам наслаждаться и такой жизнью: отвечать на вопросы, дискутировать на мете, править вопросы, ответы и описания меток.... Ведь всё это и есть жизнь нашего сообщества. Нужно жить здесь и сейчас, а не ждать того момента, когда 100% вопросов будут отвечены.

**Самое главное - не падайте духом!**

Comment: Решил сравнить статистику. Учитывая, что статистика считается за календарный год, 1000 репы на 25 сентября превращаются в 1000/267*109=408 репы на 20 апреля. На момент написания этого комментария таких участников 68 штук, что является заметным падением со 165 штук. Также число ежедневных вопросов упало со 193 до 131 штуки. Добро пожаловать на тонущий корабль.